# Print a value in React from material-ui's TextField

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I want to print (console.log) the email a user enters into the textfield here within the Dialog on the button click.
I have tried numerous methods but with the way my function is written I struggle.
Could somebody shed some light for me?

```
export default function ConsultantsHeader (props) {
  
  
  return (
            <div>
      
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
              <DialogTitle id="dialog-title">Invite Consultant</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>
                  To invite a new X, please enter their email below:
                </DialogContentText>
                <TextField
                  autoFocus
                  margin="dense"
                  id="email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  type="email"
                  fullWidth
                  color="secondary"
                  variant="outlined"
                />
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button 
                color="inherit"
                size="small"
                onClick={handleClose} >
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button 
                  onClick={inviteConsultant}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="secondary"
                  size="small">
                Send Invite
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: add a `value` prop to your `TextField` and also add a `onChange` eventlistener that will set the state with whatever value is typed and then you can console.log() the value set in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by:

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const submit = (event) => {
    const myEmail = email;

    console.log(email);

    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

and

```
<TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              fullWidth
              color="secondary"
              variant="outlined"
              value={email}
              onChange={(event) => {
                setEmail(event.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button 
            color="inherit"
            size="small"
            onClick={handleClose} >
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button 
              onClick={inviteConsultant}
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={(event) => submit(event)}>
              Send Invite
            </Button>
```